# Is there any danger of CloudFront caching a page with authorized data and serving it to an unauthorized user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I server-side render my Angular pages. If a user is authenticated, the page that is returned may have sensitive information in it. I'm new to CloudFront and am wondering how I can configure it to either not cache those pages or to cache them per user (plus a version with no sensitive info for all anonymous users). Or is this even an issue? Could CloudFront serve up some cached sensitive information to an unauthorized user?

Answer (score 0):

> Could CloudFront serve up some cached sensitive information to an unauthorized user?

Yes, generally, it absolutely could. Whether it *will* depends on a lot of specific details about the application. But generally speaking this is a good thing to be concerned with.

> how I can configure it to either not cache those pages or to cache them per user

I'm not a super advanced CloudFront user, but my approach would be CDN-agnostic: cache control. For authenticated pages you want to include response headers that indicate that the page is not to be cached. The server gets to indicate what is and isn't allowed to be cached by proxies (like CloudFront) and clients (browsers). Specifically, for any restricted-access page, I would specify `Cache-Control: private`. This tells downstream proxies they are not to cache the response, but still allows browsers to cache it locally:

> `private`
>
> Indicates that the response is intended for a single user and must not be stored by a shared cache. A private cache may store the response.

You can find more information about `Cache-Control` and other cache mechanisms on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

The advantage of a response header approach over CDN configuration is if you ever switch CDNs, you don't have to figure out how to recreate your configuration; your application is already telling the CDN how to handle the response in a completely standards-based way.